# StackoverflowException Occurring while coping a folder

Tags: android, copy, directory, android-sdcard, stack-overflow

When the following code executes with more number of nested folders and files the it gives StackOverflowException Please suggest me the way to avoid it.

```
 public void copyDirectory(File sourceLocation , File targetLocation){
    try {
        if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
            if (!targetLocation.exists() && !targetLocation.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Cannot create dir " + targetLocation.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
            String s;
            if (children != null && children.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                    s = children[i];
                    copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]), new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
                }
            }

        } else {

            // make sure the directory we plan to store the recording in exists
            File directory = targetLocation.getParentFile();
            if (directory != null && !directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Cannot create dir " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        addError(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        addError(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please suggest with the enhancements required.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

```
if (children != null && children.length > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        s = children[i];
        copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]), new File(targetLocation, children[i]));
    }
}
```

In your `copyDirectory()`, you're calling it recursively. I think some file keeps ending up in the method over and over again and you're filling your stack with by calling `New File()` for that object over and over.

Print out which file you're sending into `copyDirectory()` and you most likely will find out what your problem is.

Comment: But my requirement is to copy Whole folder along with the contents whether it is file or folder. And if it finds the Folder the I again need to copy the contents of nested folder for which I have to again call the same function i.e. copyDirectory()

Comment: You should just `LogCat` which folder you're sending into the method. You'll notice there will be one over and over, or simply too many directories. Your stack is filling up, meaning Android VM can't allocate anymore stack from the heap.

Comment: That's what the requirement is. I want to anyhow copy a folder with huge number of nested files/folders and that's what i am not able to do. for e.g. say I want to copy all the files of SDcard to some folder.